Ubuntu Studio Discover Strace bug report
I have a bug on Discover app under Ubuntu Studio, it fails to display the window but the application runs backwards. Some others have the same issue and I find that using the "strace plasma-discover" command line solve the problem on my computer. Can you tell me where and how I have to report properly this bug to the Software developer? Thanks in advance.
My system: Ubuntu Studio 24.04/KDE Plasma 5.27.11/Qt 5.15.13/Core 6.8.0-47-low latency (64bits)/graphics X11

Here is the bug report, you may add yourself as afffected. The link was provided int he release notes.

Thanks for your answer, indeed it's in the release notes... I didn't see sorry. I will put a comment in the launchpad topic thanks for your help.

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, but I upgraded some time ago to Ubuntu Studio (from stable Jelly-fish Linux Kernel 6.8.0-49-generic).
Among some other minor bugs, plasma-discover did start but did not show up and just ended without any error (or other message).
Then I found a hint on the Kubuntu thread from Joshua Holmes: sudo apt purge plasma-discover-backend-snap, followed by a restart, and that did the trick for me too. Discover works ok now!
